# Where can I download the latest version of the Ambiance theme?

Tags: themes, ambiance

Where can I obtain the latest version of the Ubuntu Ambiance themes or Ubuntu themes in general?

Specifically I am looking for a download of the 10.10 Ambiance theme for my 09.10 install and I have had no luck finding it with Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you Googled for but I found this. It's a PPA. It has a 9.10 branch to it and they have the themes backported within it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine ubuntu-mono light-themes gtk2-engines-aurora

# remove the sources after you've installed the themes
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
```

The last two lines are there to remove the webupd8 PPA after installation. It has a lot more than just the themes in and it might therefore upgrade a lot more than you want it to the next time you run update manager.

But if you run the last two lines, it should remove it from your sources and just leave you with the new theme files installed.

Comment: I found an article (http://www.webupd8.org/2010/03/ubuntu-lucid-light-themes-radiance-and.html) about the PPA you mentioned here. The article refers to the theme from Ubuntu 10.04, have they updated to the version of 10.10? I already have the 10.04 version on my system.

Comment: I just took a look at my repos and I already had nilarimogard/weupd8 added. So I can confirm that that is the 10.04 version. Oh and anyone following this method would be better off using the light-themes-fixed package instead of light-themes. The fixed package corrects some button placement issues.

Answer (score 3):

Given you want more-recent versions, your best bet is probably cherry-picking the packages you want from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/).

- [`ubuntu-mono`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/ubuntu-mono)
- [`light-themes`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/light-themes)
- [`gtk2-engines-aurora`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/gtk2-engines-aurora)
- [`gtk2-engines-murrine`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/gtk2-engines-murrine)

Download them all to a new directory, open a terminal, cd into that new directory and run `dpkg -i *.deb`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am hesitant to add anything to my system that hasn't been back ported. I don't want to break anything.